# How to write User-Defined Functions for SQLite in WinRT?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I need to write User-Defined Functions when using SQLite in a WinRT project(Windows store app), but I can not find any example out of the box. I am using "SQLite for Windows Runtime 8.1(priview)" and visual studio 2013. I know to define UDF for sqlite, I have to create a project using visual c++ and write some c callback functions, but I can not figure out where the needed header files are and how to hook my c++ dll with sqlite library for WinRT. Can anyone give me some example or idea?